# Angular 10: How to export multiple components in a module

Tags: angular, angular10

I am using Angular 10 version. There are some similar questions but they didn't solve my problem.

In my Angular project , I have made two **modules** named `post` and `static`. The `post` **module** have 10 **components**. and i want use all these components in **app.component.html**.

**what i have tried**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { PostRoutingModule } from './post-routing.module';
import { ServiceofferedComponent } from './serviceoffered/serviceoffered.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';
import { WorksampleComponent } from './worksample/worksample.component';
import { PricingComponent } from './pricing/pricing.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { ChooseserviceComponent } from './chooseservice/chooseservice.component';
import { DisplayresultComponent } from './displayresult/displayresult.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';






@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ServiceofferedComponent, FeaturesComponent, WorksampleComponent, PricingComponent, LoginComponent, SignupComponent, ChooseserviceComponent, DisplayresultComponent, HeaderComponent, BannerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PostRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[HeaderComponent],
  exports:[BannerComponent],


  
  
})
export class PostModule { }
```

I have try to use `exports:[BannerComponent],`. the first export is ok. it oesn't show any errors but for the second one it shows error. i have many more components how i will export and without export i can't use in `app.component.html`

**Error i have got**

```
   
    ERROR in src/app/post/post.module.ts:28:3 - error TS1117: An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
    
    28   exports:[BannerComponent],
         ~~~~~~~
    src/app/post/post.module.ts:28:3 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'exports'.
    
    28   exports:[BannerComponent],
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy Rahul

```
  exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        BannerComponent,
    ],
```

Only write once time, for module that you have to export.
I hope it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

To export multiple components, you should include in the `exports` array

```
    ...
    @NgModule({
              declarations: [ ServiceofferedComponent, FeaturesComponent, WorksampleComponent, PricingComponent, LoginComponent, SignupComponent, ChooseserviceComponent, DisplayresultComponent, HeaderComponent, BannerComponent],
              imports: [
                CommonModule,
                PostRoutingModule
              ],
              exports:[HeaderComponent, BannerComponent],
        })
    ...
```

You must think of the {} inside the @NgModule() as an object. An object cannot have two properties with the same name. The same concept is applied when thinking about the `object` inside the @NgModule().

Answer (score 0):

You need only one exports attribute and add all the components that needs to export in that array

```
exports:[HeaderComponent, BannerComponent]
```